# how to copy a string from one view and display it in the next view?(iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

hi everyone i am new to iphone development.

Actually i am trying with some sample app where i have a textField in the Viewcontroller and a Button,when i enter a string in the textfield and press the button it should display the same string in NextView.so can anyone help me out in doing this.

i worked with transition between one view to another view,but i need copy string from Viewcontroller1 to NextView

```
@ViewController1

-(IBAction)next
{
    NextView *Nview = [[NextView alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:Nview.view];    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an ivar in your `NextView` called "newString" *for example*, then pass a string to that ivar form your first controller.

**For Example, not tested *(and this is one of many ways you can do this)*:**

### FirstView

```
NextView * next = [[NextView alloc] initWithNewString: myTextField.text];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController: next animated: YES];
```

### NextView

```
@synthesize newString

-(id)initWithNewString:(NSString*)someString
{
    newString = someString;
    return self;
}
```

Then throughout your `NextView`, just call upon `newString` wherever you want to get the value of the previous views textField.

Comment: Thank u for ur response.. actually in UI i hv a button and a textfield, whatever i enter into textfield and press button tat shd display in nextview..Can u be more clear with sample code as i am new to iphone development

Comment: its not working...i am not able to enter anyth in textfield once i write soemth in textfield its throwing exception..in nextview i am placed a label to display..so how to make it display.

Comment: i am given IBoutlet for textfield and IBACtion method for the button when i try to enter it throws thread BAD ACCESS
in next view i wan to view in on a label..even when i click button its not moving to next view should i add [self.view addSubview:next.view];

Comment: paste the error, not just "BAD ACCESS", or even link a screenshot.

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_Interactive_iPhone_App     this may help u

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)next
{
    NextView *Nview = [[NextView alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];

    Nview.string_Object=string_to_copy;//declare string_Object in NextView.h

    [self.view addSubview:Nview.view];    
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur response..actually i hv a textfield and a button so how can i copy the entered string into nextview?

Comment: get the value entered in the textfield programatically(i.e NSString *string_to_copy = myTextField.text;//ur text field in the uiinterface
) into an string(string_to_copy) and use the above code

Comment: can u provide a code as i am new to development i am bit confused..i did wat u said but its not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
In your first view while naviagting:

```
    NextView *nav = [[NextView alloc] init];
    nav.textFieldValue = textField.text;        
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

And in your NextView's .h file create a property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *textFieldValue;
```

And in .m file synthesize it like:

```
@synthesize textFieldValue;
```

Now you can use **textFieldValue** in NextView class

P.S: Don't forget to release it :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are a beginner, [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588737/passing-nsstring-from-one-view-to-another-view/4588786#4588786) will be a good guidance for you to understand the exact flow and it will make you learn how to pass values from one class to another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach (haven't tested, but should work)

Give your textField a tag value like

```
textField.tag = 1;
```

and in NextView access it like

```
UITextField *parentViewTextField = (UITextField*)[self.superview viewWithTag:1]
```